# What does a tensor t[..., 1, tf.newaxis] ...stands for?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am beginning to work with Python and TensorFlow machine learning.

I am working through an example where I create a simple tensor representing a matrix with two rows and three columns of floats:

```py
t = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])
```

The tutorial then provides the following code:

```py
t[..., 1, tf.newaxis]
```

I am wondering what the ellipsis `...` stands for?

I cannot find any reference to this syntax in the Tensorflow API.

Answer (score 4):

"..." means "all dimensions prior to" the specified dimension.

So, in this example:

```py
t = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])
t.shape
# OP: TensorShape([2, 3])
```

Now add `newaxis`

```py
t[..., 1, tf.newaxis]
# OP: <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[2.],
#       [5.]], dtype=float32)>
t[..., 1, tf.newaxis].shape
# OP: TensorShape([2, 1])
```

Without the `newaxis`, it basically selects all the rows (...) and the first column. The shape would be (2,). Now, with the `newaxis`, the shape is (2,1).

Comment: addendum: `...` is called an ellipsis. Actually, the built-in variables `Ellipsis` and `...` have the same object `Ellipsis is ...`. (Weirdly, `Ellipsis` can be reassigned, but `...` cannot, so lean toward using `...` for consistency). The use of `...` to indicate all remaining dimensions not specified in the index comes from array indexing in NumPy, which Tensorflow is mirroring.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this. Thanks!